# Docker compose elk stack config file update does not work

Tags: image, docker-compose, logstash

I am working with the elastic stack. I downloaded a compose packe from git-hub und with

> docker-compose up

the composition runs fine.
Now I want to change my logstash default .conf file for testing. So I changed it to

```
input {
file{
        path => "C:\Program Files\develop\eclipse_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\logs\*"
        }
}

## Add your filters / logstash plugins configuration here

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    }
}
```

to get some logfiles when I run a test web app.
I thought that I have to change the config file and rebuild the image. So in the github reposiroty Directory I went in my logstash folder and changed the config file. After that I tried to execute

```
docker build .
```

to rebuild the Image.

This resulted in the output:

```
> C:\Windows\User\docker-elk\logstash>docker build . Sending build
> context to Docker daemon   5.12kB Step 1/1 : FROM
> docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:6.3.0  ---> 77bdbc2dc566
> Successfully built 77bdbc2dc566 SECURITY WARNING: You are building a
> Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files
> and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x'
> permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions
> for sensitive files and directories.
```

Finally I tried to execute

```
docker-compose up
```

But I got an error

```
Starting docker-elk_elasticsearch_1 ... error

ERROR: for docker-elk_elasticsearch_1  Cannot start service elasticsearch: b"error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/c/Windows/User/docker-elk/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml': mkdir /host_mnt/c: file exists"

ERROR: for elasticsearch  Cannot start service elasticsearch: b"error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/c/Windows/User/docker-elk/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml': mkdir /host_mnt/c: file exists"
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Can anyone tell me what I have to do to update my config file the right way? I was hoping changing and rebuilding the Image should work.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebuild using `docker-compose build` (not `docker build .`) and then do a `docker-compose up`

Also ensure you're running the commands from the right directory context - i.e. where your docker-compose.yml file exists.

From your error log it looks like its trying to reference the mount path from C:\windows\system32 on your machine which can't be right as I don't imagine you're storing your project work in the System32 directory for Windows!